# What are the guidelines for 'descriptive' and 'searchable' title?

Tags: discussion, title

Very often we get questions which have very (IMO) generic and un-descriptive title. This is mainly the case for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions. For example:

- [90s fantasy book need id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80182/90s-fantasy-book-need-id)
- [What is the TV show from 80s or 90s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80381/what-is-the-tv-show-from-80s-or-90s)
- [Book with eye on cover](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80008/book-with-eye-on-cover)
- [Need help finding fantasy book series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76750/need-help-finding-fantasy-book-series)?

The problem being that these titles are not useful for people who have the same problem.

Some non-[story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) examples:

- [Difference between cloning methods?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76440/difference-between-cloning-methods)

  - Cloning methods where? What Universe?
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55552/time-freezing-by-will

  - What canon is this referring to?
- [Is she able to kill with a mirror?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48647/is-she-able-to-kill-with-a-mirror)

  - Who can kill with a mirror?

**What are some guidelines to use, especially to help newer users improve their questions' titles?**

---

<sup>Some related extra reading:</sup>

- [When Should We Edit a Title?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/when-should-we-edit-a-title)
- [Abbreviations in question-titles, okay?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/abbreviations-in-question-titles-okay)
- [Are spoiler edits becoming excessive?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/are-spoiler-edits-becoming-excessive)
- [Is it okay to have spoilers in question titles?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-it-okay-to-have-spoilers-in-question-titles)

Please note, this question is **not** designed to single-out any particular user/question; rather to solve a supposed problem. The examples are merely that: **examples**!
I also understand that some of the examples are IMO poorly titled, you may disagree.

Comment: Regarding [tag:story-identification], see [Consensus on Story Identification titles?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/consensus-on-story-identification-titles) For general guidance, see [Writing a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title/10648#10648)

Comment: @Gilles I would go as far as saying dupe... Otherwise I can get rid of the 'story-ident' part, and leave the 'normal' ones, and write up an answer based on the [MSO discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title), and make the answer community-wiki.